# Nextcloud docker image rebranding

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, nextcloud

I want to use the nextcloud image from dockerhub as the base image for the purpose of creating the a new child image having my own company's logo in place of nextcloud and my preferred background colour.Can anyone help me with the process or any link to the solution to this?
https://nextcloud.com/changelog

```
-download this zip 

-make a docker file

-your should install apache and setup it

-change logo and colour theme in your css file

-built a new image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach is this:

1. Run the official image locally, follow the instructions on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud) to get started.
2. Modify the application using docker and shell commands. You can:

   - open a shell (`docker exec -it <container> sh`) in the running container and use console commands to edit files;
   - copy files from from the container and back with `docker cp`;
   - mount local files into the container by using `-v <src>:<dest>` in `docker run` command.
3. When you're done with editing, you need to repeat all the steps in a `Dockerfile`:

```
# use the version you used to start the local container
FROM nextcloud

# write commands that you used inside the container (if any)
RUN echo hello!

# Push edited files that you copied/mounted inside
COPY local.file /to/some/place/inside/the/image

# More possible commands in Dockerfile Reference
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/
```

After that you can use `docker build` to create your modified image.

Comment: copy files from from the container and back with docker cp;
I am trying to copy an image file from the local machine to the running nextcloud docker container using the docker cp command. But when I am trying to locate the file inside the container using shell ,I am unable to find it using ls, even though the find command shows that it exists inside the container.
I need this image file inside my container to change the logo in css file.
How do I resolve this?